# Generating a sound in Java

Tags: java, signal-processing, trigonometry

In most of the Java programs for generating a tone, the following statements are used:

```
 for(int i=0; i<milliseconds*frequency/1000; i++){
    double angle = i/(frequency/hertz)*2.0*Math.PI;
    buffer[0]=(byte)(Math.sin(angle)*volume);
 }
```

I know that the `sin` value of an angle returned by `Math.sin(angle)` function is stored in buffer array. But how does this statement work for generating a waveform

```
double angle = i/(frequency/hertz)*2.0*Math.PI;
```

Comment: Sounds more like a math question than a programming question

Comment: @UnholySheep still valid IMO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heads up....   all of your results are being stuffed in the first element of your output array.   You want to assign it to buffer[i], you currently stuff everything in buffer[0].

In your code snippet, you use the variables frequency and hertz (this will confuse people).   I believe you want to designate a desired tone frequency and you need to stipulate a sampling_rate.  With that your phase increment will end up being freq*2pi/sampling_rate, if you scale this by your index variable, 'i', that will give you discrete phase points.

Also make sure you sampling rate is at least twice the desired frequency tone (if this threw you - do a quick read on Nyquist Rate and Shannon's sampling theorem.

Best of luck